# Coding standards for phtml files

Tags: phtml

Some files such as the product listing template (with multiple nested ifs) are hard to edit without error.

I would like to be able to format phtml files with indenting appropriate for php and html, ideally as a git hook or as a command line way, e.g. in Vim. Does anyone have any method for formatting phtml files that helps, and is there a 'Zend/Varien' coding style for these files to follow?

EDIT:

I am aware that you should have all of the code that should be in the block in the block and not do random sql queries in the template. What I would like is just an easy way to get reliable indentation.

Answer (score 2):

phtml files are a bit special, as they allow everything possible in php, but you should not make use of it.

It gets harder, as magento itself does not follow any standards here and does a lot of stuff, common understanding would forbid.

A few simple rules are:

- never do a direct $model->load
- never do sql querys in loops
- /** @vat $this My_Block_Class */

the more complex issue is, how to get data into the templates.
The best way would be, to only retrieve them via the block class and only get pure data objects, nothing which causes additional querys or similar.
Keep your loops simple
such things like product lists, the better way would have been, if every product is an own block with own template, instead of putting it into a long long loop

So no, there is no real Coding Standard yet, only a lot of rules which always get broken.